# How can I add template piece to directive in angular.js after element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

F.e. for html element I can do `$.after()`, and I want to do something like for directive.

Now I have code

**html**

```
<input ng-model="job.position" ng-class="{inputError: job.errors.position}" ng-change="job.errors.position=false">
<errortooltip error="job.errors.position">
...
<script type="text/ng-template" id="error-tooltip.tpl">
   <div class="inputTooltipError" ng-show="error">
      <div class="inputTooltipErrorText">
          {{ error }}
      </div>
   </div>
</script>
```

**js**

```
.directive('errortooltip', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        error: '=error'
      },
      templateUrl: 'error-tooltip.tpl'
    };
```

But I want to make it simplier and add `errortooltip` only to input which will replace `ng-class`, `ng-change` and custom directive **and will add piece of template after input**.

```
 <input ng-model="job.position" errortooltip="job.errors.position">
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm wanting to do something similar. The problem with the answer here, as you said, is you can't use it for all kinds of form elements. Also, a bigger problem for me, is by recreating the element in the template, you can no longer do things like `$setDirty()` (the new element is disconnected from the parent form, so validation fails).

Comment: @Joao have you tried ng-transclude? I think it's a best way to do it. But it was 1,5 years ago and I don't remember how we solved it :(

Comment: I understand it's been forever. I tried transclusion, but then I couldn't access the transcluded element to manually $setDirty() on it. I found another workaround and posted the solution to my own answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035768/angularjs-directive-how-to-manipulate-checkbox-with-directive Thanks for your response though!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer would be to just change your directive to be an attribute directive, with a template that looks like what you want it to.  Then you just `replace` the existing input with the properly styled one in your template that also has a tooltip after it.

So your final HTML would look just like you described (though maybe you could condense `job.position` and `job.errors.position` into just one `job` param)

```
 <input ng-model="job.position" errortooltip="job.errors.position">
 //or
 <input errortooltip="job">
```

And then change your directive to be an attribute directive with the template you want.  If I go with the single `job` param, it might look like

```
directive('errortooltip', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      job = '=errortooltip'
    },
    templateUrl: 'error-tooltip-input.tpl'
};
```

and your new template `error-tooltip-input.tpl` would be

```
<input ng-model="job.position" ng-class="{inputError: job.errors.position}" ng-change="job.errors.position=false">
<errortooltippopup error="job.errors.position">
```

where `errortooltippopup` is a directive with the same template as your existing `error-tooltip.tpl`.

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to build attribute-based directive. I want to know how to add piece of template after element with directive applied. Like how `<input my-directive="">` can add `<span>{{ error }}</span>` AFTER input.

Comment: The way to do that is to replace the existing element with your template that also includes the 'after' element.  If you know exactly what element it will go on, you can just put it in your template, or if you need something more reusable, you can use transclusion.  But either way, you have to replace the existing HTML with template HTML.

Comment: I do not think that replacing is the right way to go. First of all it is not needed [look at my answer], moreover: what, if there are some other attributes / directives attached to the element?

Comment: Like I said, if you don't know exactly what the original element will look like (if it has extra attributes or directives), you can always use transclusion to 'inject' the original element into your template.  Really, both our answers are pretty equivalent, but I would recommend avoiding extra calls to `$compile` if there's another way.