# Angularjs directive: how to manipulate checkbox with directive

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a functional toggle switch directive for checkboxes. I've tried a few common solutions from github but none do all of the following:

- Takes into account `ng-true-value`
- Correctly update parent controller's scope
- Tie in correctly with the parent form's validation status (by this I mean, with some solutions out there, when changing the value, the form remains "pristine", etc.)

However, if I create a directive that uses transclusion to pass through the checkbox, all my requirements are met. However, I can't figure out a way to change the status of my transcluded checkbox input when my "fancy" toggle switch is clicked.

Here's a stripped-down version of my directive:

```
app.directive('toggleSwitch',function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    template: '<span class="switch" ng-click="toggleSwitch()"><span class="fancySwitch"></span><span ng-transclude></span></span>',
    link: function(scope, elem){
      scope.toggleSwitch = function(){
        //modify my fancy switch via classes (I can handle this part)

        //How do I modify the status of my checkbox? (this needs to toggle the status of the checkbox - checked or no)

      };
    }
  };
});
```

**Edit: I figured out a way to meet my goals without transclusion (see below).**

I've updated the question headline to better reflect my initial challenge and I'm adding a solution below as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I preserve the original input and apply the directive to it, I can then utilize the ngModel controller to accomplish what I want:

I prepend my custom switch using `before()`, then add a click event listener to it. By not replacing the input in the directive's template, the input is still part of the parent form and is part of the parent's scope (enabling me to access validation properties on both the element, and hence, the form overall).

When the switch is clicked, I can toggle the checkbox status using `$setViewValue` and I don't have to worry about dealing with `ng-true-value`, as that is taken care of. `$setViewValue` will "magically" cause the parent form to run validation and change the "pristine" status, etc. I can also do other things to the input itself like `$setDirty()` and `$validate()`, which I wouldn't be able to do (that I could find) using transclusion. Also, without transclusion, my directive is leaner on the view.

```
<input toggle-switch ts-true-label="Affirmative" ts-false-label="Negative" type="checkbox" name="isApproved" ng-model="sampleForm.isApproved" ng-true-value="'Yes'" ng-false-value="'No'">
```

And then the directive:

```
app.directive('toggleSwitch',function($timeout){
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      replace: false,
      require: '?ngModel',
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel){

        var switchElem;//the new switch element

        //Hide the checkbox
        elem.css({display: 'none'});

        /**
         * Toggle the switch. This function is called on the click event on the generated toggle switch
         */
        var toggleTheSwitch = function(){
          //toggle the checkbox
          if(ngModel.$viewValue === true){
            ngModel.$setViewValue(false);//note: setting view value sets the value for the view (ie, checks the checkbox, etc, then sets appropriate model view for us, also the form validates for us)
            switchElem.removeClass('checked');
          }
          else{
            ngModel.$setViewValue(true);
            switchElem.addClass('checked');
          }
          //run all checks and set appropriate status for this individual elem
          ngModel.$setDirty();
          ngModel.$setTouched();
          ngModel.$validate();
          ngModel.$render();
        };

        /**
         * Creates and adds the switch html to the dom
         */
        var createSwitch = function(){
          if(switchElem){
            switchElem.remove();
          }
          //Create the toggle switch
          var switchHTML = '';
          switchHTML += '<span class="switch' + (attrs.class ? ' ' + attrs.class : '') + ' ' + (ngModel.$viewValue ? 'checked' : '') +'" >';
          switchHTML +=   '<span class="label checkedLabel">'+(attrs.tsTrueLabel ? attrs.tsTrueLabel: '')+'</span>';
          switchHTML +=   '<span class="label uncheckedLabel">'+(attrs.tsFalseLabel ? attrs.tsFalseLabel: '')+'</span>';
          switchHTML +=   '<small></small>';
          switchHTML += '</span>';

          switchElem = angular.element(switchHTML);//create angular jqlite object
          elem.before(switchElem);//add new stuff before the checkbox
        };


        //After the directive is done loading, we can access ngModel controller
        $timeout(function() {
          //create the switch
          createSwitch();

          //set onclick event
          switchElem.on('click', function(){
            toggleTheSwitch();
          });
        });

      }

    };
  });
```

For anybody else, feel free to use it. You'll have to create the css yourself, of course.